# what is the bootstrap .btn-default's background-color on hover

Tags: css, twitter-bootstrap

Quick question, what is the boostrap's .btn-default's backgorund-color on hover. Chrome inspect element doesn't give me the hover value.

Need to change a default button, here's a snippet.

```
<button type="button" class="btn btn-default">On</button>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> what is the bootstrap .btn-default's background-color on hover

Here is the declaration:

```
.btn-default:hover {
    color: #333;
    background-color: #e6e6e6;
    border-color: #adadad;
}
```

If you want to inspect the CSS of elements that are state based, like `:active`, `:focus`, `:hover` or  `:visited`, open the developer console (F12 in Chrome) and click on the `pin` icon on the top right corner.

This will open a panel that will let you force the state of the element, making it easier to inspect.

Comment: Great! Thanks a bunch. Thanks for the chrome inspect information as well.